# Pass and fail in Esperanto?

Tags: translation

When we're talking about testing, something can "pass" or "fail" a test. (Bestanden/nicht bestanden). How is this expressed in Esperanto? I'm looking for one word for each expression, like this: "First test - pass", "Second test - fail".

Answer (score 3):

To pass something:

> Sukcesi en io

To fail something:

> Malsukcesi en io

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that once anyone sees the word "ekzameno", almost any way that you choose to express the pass/fail concept will be understood, because it's expected in that context. As far as I know there is no way of describing this that is universally well-established by custom, but I have little experience taking tests in Esperanto (maybe someone who has taken or administered an exam or who has been an Esperanto student or educator could provide some insight on test-taking vocabulary?)

Here is an option that I think would be generally understood:

```
Unua ekzameno - sukceso
Dua ekzameno - malsukceso
```

I think this would strike people as meaning that either a success or a failure occured regarding the tests, and can be disambiguated by context. You might also express it as adjectives intended to describe an implied subject: "sukcesa/malsukcesa" but it might be misunderstood as the test itself being unsuccessful (which you might want, let's say if you wanted to say whether a computer managed to perform some kind of test or if it failed to). As a verb, you might try "sukcesis/malsukcesis" with somewhat of a similar comprehension problem regarding whether the test itself or an unnamed but implied test-taker is the actual subject. I'm not sure if using noun forms totally avoids this problem or not but it seems more straightforward to me.